# Phonegap 3.3 android local build issue with InAppBrowser plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap 3.3 CLI to create project and add plugins. I added the org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser plugin without any version , after that phonegap build andriod command failed with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined" error.

I tried some experimentation later to remove and the same plugin with different versions, but only 0.2.3, 0.3.0 and 0.3.3 worked. Can anyone help me here ? if it Phonegap version specific and i saw some tickets where it says issues is resolved, but latest version with Phonegap 3.3 didnot work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>

<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 

 xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"id="testpgappbrowser.id" version="1.0.0">

<name>testPGAppBrowser</name>

<description>Hello World sample application that responds to deviceready event.</description>

<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

<preference name="orientation" value="default"/>

<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>

<preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>

<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>

<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>

<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>

<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>

<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/> 

<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/> 

<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>

<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>

<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7"/>

<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"/>
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"/>
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"/>
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57"/>
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114"/>
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144"/>
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"/>
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"/>
```

regards
Swapna

Comment: can you please share the config.xml file ? Thanks.

Comment: i have uploaded the file here, please let me know if u have access https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/0B7la8HOyJ4h9aEd0RkpyZzRpRWc

Comment: Sorry :-( no access, Better to put it here in your post.

Comment: when i paste the contents it is showing as html page, can you let me know how to share the xml contents.

Comment: Thanks for sharing config.xml , but I am slightly confused [1] We can see duplicated lines! [2] I am not able to find org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser defined. Can you please check?

Comment: Sorry while i was trying to copy it manytimes it got messedup, i have the right contents now. Please check

Comment: Seems to be format wrong with plugin: <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" /> Also, try by changing 
<access origin="*"/>

Comment: Please add   <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.3.0" />

Answer (score 0):

Here some changes need to be made in your config.xml :

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" /> 

<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />

<access origin="*"/>
```

Comment: when i add these lines it works, but i have few questions, why is this needed only for the AppBrowserr plugin ? for other plugins just adding the following in config.xml works, <gap:plugin name=<plugin_name>/>. And the access origin tag is for the plugin or it is for entire config.xml ? can you please help here.

Comment: Also one more point, usually after i have added the plugin with above syntax, after build in the platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml i can see the plugin feature tag , but now that we are already adding the tag in the config.xml in the www/ folder , so i really wont know if the plugin is compiled. is there anyother way to know ?

Comment: access origin tag is for entire config.xml.

Comment: Feature tag is not necessary. When you include plugin in tag, the necessary files will be added by phonegap build.

Comment: ok , but why do we have to add the plugin tag for AppBrowser only, whereas it works for other plugins, and is the Phonegap version important in this case